# UITextView rendering strange characters after changing font

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

So I've got a `UITextView/NSTextView` that dynamically updates it's styling via an `NSMutableAttributedString`. I'm noticing that when a subsection of the text's font's spacing changes some strange characters render where the font was changed, see this gif:

[image: weird characters]

Minimally I'm updating a section of the `NSMutableAttributedString` with the following block

```
attr.setAttributes([
    .foregroundColor : textColor,
    .font : UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .thin),
], range: range)
```

Before the weird characters:

```
Hello
{
    NSColor = "Catalog color: System labelColor";
    NSFont = "\".AppleSystemUIFont 13.00 pt. P [] (0x7fed6ef77420) fobj=0x7fed6ef77420, spc=3.58\"";
}'''
nice stuff
'''{
    NSColor = "Catalog color: System labelColor";
    NSFont = "\".AppleSystemUIFontMonospaced-Regular 13.00 pt. P [] (0x7fed6ef7aa50) fobj=0x7fed6ef7aa50, spc=8.04\"";
}
Hello{
    NSColor = "Catalog color: System labelColor";
    NSFont = "\".AppleSystemUIFont 13.00 pt. P [] (0x7fed6ef77420) fobj=0x7fed6ef77420, spc=3.58\"";
}
```

When the weird characters are rendering:

```
Hello
'''
nice stuff
''
Hello{
    NSColor = "Catalog color: System labelColor";
    NSFont = "\".AppleSystemUIFont 13.00 pt. P [] (0x7fed6ef77420) fobj=0x7fed6ef77420, spc=3.58\"";
}
```

Has any experienced weird artifacts and issues like this?

Comment: Do you have a full reproducible sample? I'm wondering if it's not an issue of encoding, UTF8 (by default String count) vs UTF16 length (NSRange, NSAttributedString length, NSString length).

Comment: I actually figured out my predicament. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: It would be helpful to post the solution for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `NSTextStorage` if you don't mark the range with `NSTextStroage.edited` after styling the ranges you can end up with some of this artifacting.